# Magento REST API not working in PHP

Tags: api, rest, magento

Whenever I try to call Magento's rest resources via PHP, I get an `HTTP 500 Internal Server Error`. My link is, in accordance to Magento's REST API, http://mymagento.com/api/rest/products.

Everything is set up properly and whenever I try to access it via the browser, the response is a page with the XML data I want. Same thing goes for the RESTClient plugin for Firefox.

I also get the internal server error whenever I try to do an authorised request as a customer.

Does anyone know why this is happening? I ran out of ideas an hour ago or so.

Comment: have you got the answer for this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857981/error-while-using-rest-api-in-magento/13858760#13858760 this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you just got that problem (only) then,

**500 errors in the HTTP cycle**

Any client (e.g. your Web browser or our CheckUpDown robot) goes through the following cycle when it communicates with the Web server:

- Obtain an IP address from the IP name of the site (the site URL
  without the leading 'http://'). This lookup (conversion of IP name to
  IP address) is provided by domain name servers (DNSs).
- Open an IP socket connection to that IP address.
- Write an HTTP data stream through that socket.
- Receive an HTTP data stream back from the Web server in response.
  This data stream contains status codes whose values are determined by
  the HTTP protocol. Parse this data stream for status codes and other
  useful information.

This error occurs in the final step above when the client receives an HTTP status code that it recognises as '500'. (Last updated: March 2012).

**Fixing 500 errors - general**

This error can only be resolved by fixes to the Web server software. It is not a client-side problem. It is up to the operators of the Web server site to locate and analyse the logs which should give further information about the error.