# Error while using REST api in magento

Tags: api, magento, rest

I have set up magento locally in my system using XAMPP

I have created a file in root directory named dm.php with the contents

```
<?php
/**
* Example of products list retrieve using Customer account via Magento REST API. OAuth authorization is used
*/
$callbackUrl = "http://localhost/dm.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://localhost/mage2/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://localhost/mage2/oauth/authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://localhost/mage2/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://localhost/mage2/api/rest';
$consumerKey = 'enhksf7u33p3snubewb6zcq0z9c63bvv';
$consumerSecret = 'p7e835cdcxofokeep749jgzz4l1e306p';

session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();

    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
        exit;
    } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
        exit;
    } else {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products";
        $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl);
        $productsList = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse());
        print_r($productsList);
    }
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

But this is giving me the following error

```
Fatal error: Class 'OAuth' not found in D:\Webserver\xampp\htdocs\dm.php on line 19
```

Can anybody shed some light on this
Thanks

Since oauth is not possible to install in xampp windows i changed the contents of my dm.php file to this.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/mage2/api/rest/customers');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$customers = curl_exec($ch);
echo $customers;
?>
```

Now i am getting an error like this

```
{"messages":{"error":[{"code":403,"message":"Access denied"}]}}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is Ouath enabled  in the Xampp server? Its happens due to that

Comment: @chanz: i checked now. its not enabled.But i think there no way we can install oauth in xampp

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html this link might help you

Comment: Consumer key,
Consumer secret,
Access token,
Access token secret, are required

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all 
Go to magento admin panel `System->Webservice->RESt Roles->Guest->Resources Access ->SET ALL`

Similarly Go to `System->Webservice->RESt Attribute->Guest->Resources Access ->SET ALL`

Then Hit this url `http://****/chanchal/magento/api/rest/products` in web Browser and check what error it shows....

According to me it must show product in your website in `xml` format.

Please let me know..

EDIT:
I configured a localhost just now and got this output  refer the Screenshot. Be sure there is product in your magento.[image]

Similarly follow the above steps for admin,customer then create a  Ouath consumer from admin panel , Install RESTClient For Mozilla Firefox And  follow [Here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html)

These for steps are necessary for the setup..the link might help you..

Authentication Endpoints

1.`/oauth/initiate` - this endpoint is used for retrieving the Request Token.

2.`/oauth/authorize` - this endpoint is used for user authorization (Customer).

3.`/admin/oauth_authorize` - this endpoint is used for user authorization (Admin).

4.`/oauth/token` - this endpoint is used for retrieving the Access Token.

Let me know if you have any issues.

Best of luck

Comment: the output i get is this <magento_api/>, only this much

Comment: Do you have product in your magento.. it should show the product listing

Comment: I am sure there is no product in your magento.

Comment: sorry it was my mistake, i had 3 installation of magento in my system and this ones catalog was empty.Thanks for your valuable time.And adding to this how can we make this access protected using a username ans password?

Comment: i am using xampp with windows.i am not able to install oauth module in windows just see my question <Fatal error: Class 'OAuth' not found in D:\Webserver\xampp\htdocs\dm.php on line 19> this is the error i am getting. is there any workaround for this?

Comment: When I first tried to configured Rest for localhost i was not able to install oauth for Wamp server i tried pear.php.net/ but was not able to configured,so i configured that in lINUX SERVER and it went good.

Comment: @chanz I have a products in magento and also i was already install oauth extension in zend for windows but when we open url like this 'http://127.0.0.1/magento/api/rest/products', it display 'Access denied'.

Comment: @chanz you know how to get all category list using magento rest oauth api?

Comment: by default in magneto Rest api there is no method for category listing.

Comment: @chanz  Can you help me regard rest api customer getting error : https://snag.gy/MVINwS.jpg

Answer (score 2):

A bit of code modifications will easily solve this error `403 forbidden`.

What magento engine does is that it uses the default `guest` user to provide access to the REST api methods. The guest user does not have much powers so it should be better to change this functionality of magento. There are 2 ways of doing this:

1) Quick and dirty fix: 
in the file **/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Auth.php**, change the value of:
 `DEFAULT_USER_TYPE = 'guest'` 
to
 `DEFAULT_USER_TYPE = 'admin'`. 
In the file 
**/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Auth/Adapter.php**, 
change this line from 
`return (object) array('type' => Mage_Api2_Model_Auth::DEFAULT_USER_TYPE, 'id' => null);` 
to this:
 
`return (object) array('type' => Mage_Api2_Model_Auth::DEFAULT_USER_TYPE, 'id' => '1');`

This way the authentication system will not be broken.

2) Proper and long run fix: 
Override the two functionalities using the magento overriding mechanism to have a better solution in accordance to magento standards. This way the core files will be intact.

Comment: I found out that mine is really a very dirty solution. It makes the resource available publicly without any authentication. People are advised to use this one sensibly. I will not consider this as a solution at all. This can be just used to test whether the resource is available or not. This should NOT go in production environment at all.

Comment: Thank you Friend, for testing I have used 1st solution. can you help me for proper solution.

Comment: There are a number of tutorials available on how to override modules in magento like http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/ and many more. You can go through them very easily to find the exact way.

Comment: Not secure, there is an 'admin' user group for a reason, and that is to put certain functionality behind a wall. Opening that up to the world, bad idea!

Comment: Yes Dan, this is what I stated as soon as I found that out. This is why I mentioned the term dirty.

Answer (score 0):

We use this link to install oauth for php. Its good and easy to add extension for php.

[install oauth php](http://katieseaborn.com/masters/prototype/installing-oauth-on-windows/)

I hope it helps to all and would solved 'OAuth' not found fatal error.

Comment: you were add php_oauth.dll file in C:\xampp\php\ext folder and change php.ini file by adding extension=php_oauth.dll in C:/xampp/php/php.ini file.?

Comment: I have a zend with windows and oauth is completely working in my system. zend is best so use zend server.

Comment: thats it, in my question i mentioned mine is XAMPP.I don't think it will work in XAMPP.but not quite sure.There will always be a way to do it which i don't know :)

Comment: @BharatChodvadiya For me http://127.0.0.1/anusthana/api/rest/products   working, if ti try with  http://127.0.0.1/anusthana/api/rest/customers i am getting error like ->  https://snag.gy/MVINwS.jpg, can you pls help me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was struggling for a week but just try insatlling new version of xammp or wamp with supports ouath.The better solution was ,I installed Ammps 1.9 and in php5.4 I resolved the extension of oauth but still make sure that you select the proper php for extension oauth is supported (php5.4)

Answer (score 0):

For installing Oauth : http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html

Installing PHP Extension for Oauth :
1. Download php_oauth.dll file and add it under C:\xampp\php\ext\
2. add  [PHP_OAUTH] extension=php_oauth.dll  in php.ini

Comment: For me http://127.0.0.1/anusthana/api/rest/products   working, if ti try with  http://127.0.0.1/anusthana/api/rest/customers i am getting error like ->  https://snag.gy/MVINwS.jpg, can you pls help me @alok

Comment: There must be some authorization issue thats why you are getting access denied.