# In magento retrive the details of a single product by REST url

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento-1.6

As I am new to magento, I have downloaded magento sample data to mysql database. In the browser if i give the REST URL like this: *http://192.168.1.101:8010/magento/api/rest/products* it returns the list of products in XML format. But i want the details of a single product. Then what I have to do??

*http://192.168.1.101:8010/magento/api/rest/products* is the url I got from the magento site.. But they havent give for the product details.

Do i need to wirte any code for my reqiurement??

For *http://192.168.1.101:8010/magento/api/rest/customers* it shows access denied... How can i get resolve of this..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please go thoroughly wiki of magento, it might help you.[here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html) is the link.

For single product your REST request would be as follows 
 `magentohost/api/rest/products/8`  where 8 is the id of product.

For second question i.e "Accessed denied" is this due to permission , you have create consumer for admin or customer to get that resource. please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857981/error-while-using-rest-api-in-magento/13858760#13858760)

Comment: Thank u chanz.. 1st answer is working... but for the http://localhost/api/rest/customers it has to show all the customers list.. but it shows access denied... I have given "resource access: All" for everyone... But it wont work

Comment: My images are in the magento root folder. when I give localhost/api/rest/products/166 it shows the image url tag also. but when i give localhost/api/rest/166/images, it shows only '<magento_api/>'... I mean that it says null..but how it shows image url tag when we gave only Id.?????

Comment: sorry that should not happen as far i am concern it should show the images for the following url. I have tested in my magento is it is showing fine there.