# Android rest client to magento

Tags: android, magento, rest, oauth

I'm trying to build an Android app that consumes data from a Magento Server. I'm looking for a good sample (using oAuth authentication) or even a framework that would help me to make it faster. Any tip?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Me also Googled for the same nearly a week, At last I got one tutorial here

http://gmartinezgil.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/using-the-magento-rest-api-in-java-with-scribe/

I follow the method, But I can't produce the result.This may help you.

Check this also- [android connect to magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112174/android-connect-to-magento/25947581#25947581)

Comment: have you found the solution to connect magento rest api with android?

Comment: I found it without oauth is like the second link, With Oauth is not working  for me.

Comment: then how are you accessing customer api's as well as admin?

Comment: Break the oauth for now(i know its a bad idea). Then rewrite all the default magento api url for security. Here is how you can break the oauth. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857981/error-while-using-rest-api-in-magento/17441312#17441312

Comment: ok but i am not a php developer righ now, have you read this blog http://blog.yasuoza.com/2013/12/16/scribe-java-in-android/   ?

Comment: NO,now only I saw this, Because I am in an urgent I dont want to waste time in oauth at starting. So I avoid it. Now only i am going to start with oauth.