# How to solve 403 Forbidden error in REST client

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am using RESTClient  add-on for REST API in magento. In this while i am try to retrive the products means it will show the following error.

[image: Screen Shot]

How to solve this error. i am follwoing this [click](http://inchoo.net/magento/configure-magento-rest-and-oauth-settings/)  to use the RESTClient.

Please Help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

just verify that your .htaccess file is in root folder of magento

Follow this link it might help you :

https://technojega.wordpress.com/2015/07/10/magento-rest-api-oauth-authorization/

Comment: i can't get the token. please help me

Comment: Try this link http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html

Comment: I try that also . in that how to run the authentication endpoints?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857981/error-while-using-rest-api-in-magento